# Groovy. Get parameters values where part of values are parametrized

Tags: bash, groovy

Hi I would like to do something like this...

```
DEV_HOST = "some hostname"
DEV_INST = "2"
DEV_TEST_HOST = "some other hostname"
DEV_TEST_INST = "3"

get_values(DEV_TEST_HOST)

def get_values(environment) {
  println environment
  println ${environment}_INST
}
```

Desired output should be:

```
some other hostname
3
```

Is it even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Your variable naming is not consistent. Why is it `DEV_TEST_INST` and not `DEV_TEST_HOST_INST`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. It should be:

DEV_HOST = "some hostname"
DEV_INST = "2"
DEV_TEST_HOST = "some other hostname"
DEV_TEST_INST = "3"

I've corrected first post.

Comment: Where are these values declared (DEV_HOST, etc.)? Are they environment variables?

Comment: At the top of my script. They can be env variables, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass the value to a function and then introspect what the
variable was named when calling that function (or let's say, if it's
possible, then it's just so many levels of overkill).

Assuming you have some sort of map (e.g. the environment), you pass in
the key you are interested instead.  Then do all the transformations on
the key and then ask the environment for the key.  E.g.

```
def env = [
  DEV_TEST_HOST: "some other hostname" ,
  DEV_TEST_INST: "3",
]
                           
get_values(env, "DEV_TEST_HOST")
                             
def get_values(env, key) {
  println env[key]        
  println env[key.replace('HOST', 'INST')]
}
```

Comment: but how to make it universal? Because this is the main goal.

When I do:
get_values(env, "DEV_TEST_HOST") I would like to have DEV_TEST_XXX values.
get_values(env, "DEV_HOST") I would like to have DEV_HOST values.

Comment: Ok it works! Thank you very much!

`code`
def env  = [
DEV_TEST_HOST: "test dev",
DEV_TEST_INST: "test inst",
DEV_HOST: "dev host",
DEV_INST: "dev inst"
]

get_values(env, "DEV_TEST_HOST")

get_values(env, "DEV_HOST")

def get_values(env, key) {
        println env[key]
        println env[key.replace('HOST','INST')]
}`code`

Comment: You could pass in the prefix and then add HOST/INST inside get values etc.  This is just an example to to deal with the general problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to reorganize you map in more clear way, you can use this:

```
env = [
    DEV: [
        HOST: "some hostname",
        INST: "2"
    ],
    DEV_TEST: [
        HOST: "some other hostname",
        INST: "3"
    ]
]

def get_values(v) {
    println env[v].HOST
    println env[v]."HOST"
    println env[v].INST
    println env[v]."INST"
}

get_values("DEV")
get_values("DEV_TEST")
```